# Reference to integer as static variable inside python class

Tags: python

I'm trying to have a static int inside a class in python. But it doesn't work.

Here's an example of what I've implemented :

```
class MyDict(dict):

    STR_DEPTH = -1

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyDict, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.__dict__.update(name = kwargs.get("name", ""))

    def __str__(self):
        self.STR_DEPTH += 1
        res = self.name + '\n'
        for k in self.keys():
            res += '\t'*self.STR_DEPTH + k + " = "  + str(self[k])
            res += '\n'
        self.STR_DEPTH -= 1
        return res

def main():
    d1 = MyDict(one=MyDict())
    d1["two"] = 2
    d1["one"]["one"] = 1
    d1["one"]["two"] = MyDict(three=3)
    d1["four"] = 4
    print d1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and i'm expecting :

```
four = 4
two = 2
one = 
    two = 
        three = 3

    one = 1
```

but it doesn't work that way. If i'm not mistaking, int aren't references and it's not the same "STR_DEPTH" in every instances of my class.

I already know the list-of-length-1 trick and the empty-type trick, but do i really need to resort do clumsy unreadable trick ?

Isn't there a better way since i'm inside a class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have:

```
    self.STR_DEPTH += 1
```

replace that with:

```
    MyDict.STR_DEPTH += 1
```

and the same where you decrement the value.

Assigning to `self.STR_DEPTH` will create a new instance variable which hides access to the class variable through `self`. You can use `self.STR_DEPTH` to access the class variable provided you don't have an instance variable of the same name, but if you want to rebind the class variable you have to refer to it directly.

Note that `self.STR_DEPTH += 1` is really just shorthand for `self.STR_DEPTH = self.STR_DEPTH + 1` so even if the right hand `self.STR_DEPTH` picks up the class variable the assignment still happens back to the instance variable.